# SlickGrid bind event to checkbox

Tags: events, checkbox, slickgrid

Hy,

I want to bind an event to

```
< INPUT type=checkbox value='true' name='selectedRows[]' id='sel_id_" +  i +  "'class='editor-checkbox selected_rows' hideFocus />
```

but I couldn't find a good jquery selector. If I put an onclick event I can only call functions that are not in the `$(function() { });` block and in this case I can't make use of some core functions.

Here is the link to it http://li.ro/4bJw

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've added a sample implementation at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html

This is part of the 2.0 release.